Prove that the usual metric and other metric induce the same topology
I am working on A course on Borel sets, by S.M. Srivastava. There is this problem I am working on that states the following:
Show that both the metrics $d_1$ and $d_2$ on $\mathbb{R^n}$ deﬁned in 2.1.1 induce the same topology. This topology is called the usual topology.
The metrics it is referring to are the euclidean distance ($d_1$), and
$$ d_2 = \max\{|x_i − y_i | : 1 ≤ i ≤ n\}$$
I proceeded with the following reasoning:

We are trying to find that for every subset of the topology induced by the metric $d_1$ ($\tau_1$), that subset is also contained in the topology induced by $d_2$ ($\tau_2$).

For that, given any set $U\in\tau_1$ (which we know that satisfies the open ball condition for the first metric), this set should also satisfy the open ball condition for the second metric.

If $B_1\subseteq U \Rightarrow \forall x \in U, d_1(x,y) < r$.

Also, $d_1$ is always going to be finitely larger or smaller than $d_2$. In particular, if $x_i-y_1 > 1$ for at least one $i$, then $d_1(x,y) \geq d_2(x,y)$, and if not, then which is one is bigger or smaller is not clear but is finite (if both elements are the same, then both distances are 0, else both distances are greater than 1).

Therefore, if we put $k=\frac{d_1(x,y)}{d_2(x,y)}$, and $r = k\cdot r'$ we can say that if $y \in B_1(x,r) \Rightarrow y \in B_2(x,r)$.

From this results we can conclude that there is a relation between the distance functions that could allow us to map a ball generated by one of them to the other.


I am quite unsure that the procedure is totally correct. Specially, I am not sure that the last 2 steps actually allow as to conclude the result that we want.

This is just a special case of equivalent metrics: There are numbers $a$ and $b$ such that for all $x,y\in X$, we have $d_1(x,y)\le a d_2(x,y)$ and $d_2(x,y)\le b d_1(x,y)$. It is not hard to show that equivalent metrics induce the same topology. -- For your two metrics, one can show that $a=\sqrt n$ and $b=1$ do the job. Since your attempt does not mention "$\sqrt n$" anywhere, it is quite certainly wrong. In fact, looking at your step 5, it seems your method would work for arbitrary metrics, but of course it shouldn't.
